# How to edit Time Series Insights (preview) instances by uploading a JSON?

Tags: azure, azure-timeseries-insights

I have instances created in my TSI preview (Azure - Time series insights) environment and can edit them fine with the UI. However I have a lot of instances I would have to edit so doing a batch edit is necessary. However whenever I upload a Json document in the instances page nothing changes in the selected instance I'm trying to edit. Here is the json I am attempting to upload:

```
    {
      "put":{
        "typeId": "a5e1a000-3f1b-4e50-9900-4c6591f89442",
        "timeSeriesId": [
          "MET01_IRD_GHI_B_TRND"
        ]   
      }
    }
```

This should be specifying that the instance with Time Series ID MET01_IRD_GHI_B_TRND should now be assigned a specific type. The json uploads successfully however nothing seems to change. I have also tried adding a new instance by creating a new unique timeseriesID in the json payload, this also leads to no results.

I am fairly new to Time Series Insights so I'm not sure even if this should work, but I'm sure there should be some way of batch uploading edits to instances etc.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your file should contain an array of instances. Try this:

```
{
    "put": [
    {
        "typeId": "a5e1a000-3f1b-4e50-9900-4c6591f89442",
        "timeSeriesId": [
             "MET01_IRD_GHI_B_TRND"
        ]   
    }
  ]
}
```